# Why is this a fragment?

Tags: sentence-structure

What is missing in the following sentence? Shows as a fragment.

> Concluding their waltz by waltzing the boy to his bed, but the boy not ready for their time together to end clings to his “papa’s” shirt to keep his father with him.

Comment: There's no predicate. Take out the "but" and put a period after "end". That will fix your problem.

Comment: For more context, this appears to be commentary on the poem [My Papa's Waltz](http://edwardbyrne.blogspot.com/2007/06/theodore-roethke-my-papas-waltz.html) by Theodore Roethke which is often use in classroom discussions of 20th century poetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The but is extraneous. Take out the but, and add two commas.

> Concluding their waltz by waltzing the boy to his bed, the boy, not ready for their time together to end, clings to his “papa’s” shirt to keep his father with him.

Added commas after boy and end.

"Concluding ... bed" is descriptive. "The boy" is the subject of the sentence, and clings is the predicate. However, with the but, there is no subject in the sentence. Without the commas, it flows very unnaturally, though the meaning can be parsed.